# Find and Replace text in entire Google Drive folder, headers, footers, google docs using a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, drive

I have numerous Google Docs with a header and footer.  Multiple links on our intranet to these documents exist so I don't want to make new documents.  There are hundreds of documents to update.

I need to update the physical address and header/footer letterhead in these documents.  I need to copy the images, formatting, tables, etc in the header and footers too.

I wish they were more like CSS or templates that could be changed across multiple documents at once.

Multiple considerations have been exhausted trying to do this:

1. Apply a template with a new header and footer to an existing document - does not seem to be possible.  Each has to be copied and pasted manually.
2. Applications like Dreamweaver allow you to Find and Replace to all files in a folder.  There is no way to do this that I could find for Google Docs.

Is there a way to automate this tedious process? Even a starting point hint!

```
    function replaceHeaderAndFooter() {
  
 var headerToCopyandPaste = DocumentApp.openById("<SourceDocID>").getHeader().copy();  // ID contains source header
 var footerToCopyandPaste = DocumentApp.openById("<SourceDocID>").getHeader().copy();  // ID contains source footer
  
  
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("<FOLDER ID>").getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    
  var headerSectionToBeReplaced = doc.getHeader()
  var footerSectionToBeReplaced = doc.getFooter()
    
    headerSectionToBeReplaced.clear()
    
    headerSectionToBeReplaced = headerToCopyandPaste

  }
}
```

I've also tried to put everything in the template (images, paragraphs, formatting) into a single table in the header, for example.  This code does not work either.  The following code Results in the following error:

The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.HeaderSection.appendTable

```
    function replaceHeaderAndFooter() {
  
 const headerToCopyandPaste = DocumentApp.openById("<SourceDocID>").getHeader().getTables().toString();  // ID contains source header
 const footerToCopyandPaste = DocumentApp.openById("<SourceDocID>").getHeader().copy();  // ID contains source footer
  
  
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("<FolderID>").getFiles();  //ID contains folder that has Google Docs that will have Header and Footer Replaced
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    
  var headerSectionToBeReplaced = doc.getHeader()
  var footerSectionToBeReplaced = doc.getFooter()
    
  headerSectionToBeReplaced.clear();

 headerSectionToBeReplaced.appendTable(headerToCopyandPaste)
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way, and that is using replaceText(). If your files do belong in a single folder, then it is easy to search and replace them all.

```
function replaceTextSpecificFolder() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("<folder_id>").getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
   doc.replaceText("<replace>", "<new string>");
  }
}
```

<folder_id> is everything that comes after “folders/” in the URL when you visit the Google Drive folder.

For example, if the URL was
"https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/moqwiSADN921m03uhwdJ",then the Folder ID would be “moqwiSADN921m03uhwdJ”.

**EDIT:**
As for the other items like formatting, tables, images, etc., you can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table). Find it under its respective class on the left pane. (E.g. You can find table functions under Table Class)

Comment: THANKS!  Is there a way to get the formatting and images too?  Would this be HTML code? Or a way to copy the "code" of the header to find and replace?

Or even a way to delete a header for all documents, and replace with new header that includes images, table, etc

Comment: Hi @BD, I updated the answer above. I've provided you the documentations on which functions to use for your script. If this does help you with your problems in any way, kindly upvote and pick this as the answer to your question.



If you have more clarifications, you can add a comment here so I can further assist you in your problem.

Comment: Thank you!  I would have to delete the header and create a new header/table with the different fonts, the image/logo, etc., alignments, etc.

Is there a way to EXTRACT that blob of information from a google doc with the correct formatting, fonts, sizing, spacing, logo image, table, etc from a reference document, and REPLACE it in the other outdated documents?

Comment: I don't think there is, but free to check the documentation.

What I can confirm is that we have a function named getAttributes in the classes (e.g. footer, header, etc.) I checked on the documentation. Depending on what you need, you may execute the classes' getAttributes function per object you need to get, recreate and delete.

Comment: Hello - I was able to figure out copying a source header and footer (I think), and clearing the headers and footers in a folder in code above... but can't figure out how to paste / insert the copied source header and footer with all attributes (table, paragraph, images)
Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Currently there is a table, paragraph, and image in the header.
I also tried making a new template where all items are within a table.
I tried to  headerSectionToBeReplaced.appendTable(headerToCopyandPaste) but this results in error "Exception: The parameters (DocumentApp.HeaderSection) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.HeaderSection.appendTable."

Is there a way to copy the table from the template header (with images, formatting, etc), and append that table (with images, formatting, etc) to the docs within a folder?

Comment: Hi @BD, kindly post your future issues in a new post so others can also see your current issues. The issues you encounter is unfamiliar to me and I might not be able to help you with them.