# Get Header and Footer from template Google Doc, and apply to all docs in a Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, flysystem-google-drive

I need help applying a header and footer that contains tables, paragraphs, and images (branding content/letterhead) across all Google docs in a Google drive folder.

GOALS:

1. Get/Copy header from source document that contains tables, paragraphs, and images.
2. Paste/Apply/Replace header copied in 1 to all documents in a Google drive folder
3. Do same for Footer.
4. Don't require programatic "appending" to existing footers.

I wish there was a way to do CSS or something similar for templates that could be applied to a batch of google docs... but I believe scripting is the only way.

This is adding on to this post: [Find and Replace text in entire Google Drive folder, headers, footers, google docs using a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990217/find-and-replace-text-in-entire-google-drive-folder-headers-footers-google-do)

```
function replaceHeaderAndFooter() {
  
 const headerToCopyandPaste = DocumentApp.openById("<SourceDocID>").getHeader().getTables().toString();  // ID contains source header
 const footerToCopyandPaste = DocumentApp.openById("<SourceDocID>").getHeader().copy();  // ID contains source footer
  
  
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("<FolderID>").getFiles();  //ID contains folder that has Google Docs that will have Header and Footer Replaced
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    
  var headerSectionToBeReplaced = doc.getHeader()
  var footerSectionToBeReplaced = doc.getFooter()
    
  headerSectionToBeReplaced.clear();
footerSectionToBeReplaced.clear();

 headerSectionToBeReplaced.appendTable(headerToCopyandPaste); //This does not work
 footerSectionToBeReplaced = footerToCopyandPaste    // This does not work
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the current issue of your script? 2. About `a header and footer that contains tables, paragraphs, and images (branding content/letterhead)`, can you provide the sample image of your situation? And, in your case, the header and footer of 1st page are different from other pages? 3. I cannot understand about `Paste/Apply/Replace header copied in 1 to all documents in a Google drive folder` and `Don't require programatic "appending" to existing footers.`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Thanks - Yes here is an example.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hYlaz7AO3SnyLd07JAiFsUv4levSXudbl2zSlynogyM/edit

I want to copy the header and footer from a template document, and replace all headers and footers in the documents in a specific folder.  e.g. We rearrange the partners, change the logo, etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, the destination Documents have multiple pages and the texts have already been set, and you want to copy the header and footer of the template document to all pages of each destination document as the overwrite. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: @Tanaike you are correct. Is there a way to replace all headers and footers in gdocs documents in a specific google drive folder with (this header and footer from a template doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hYlaz7AO3SnyLd07JAiFsUv4levSXudbl2zSlynogyM/edit)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm it. Can I ask you about the number of Google Document files in the specific folder? And, the specific folder has the sub folders?

Comment: Thanks.  All the documents are in a single folder.  That folder does have sub folders but I can change that if that makes the coding more difficult.  They are on a Shared Drive but I don't think that makes a difference.  Lots of links go to these documents on our intranet, but to keep those links updated, hundreds of documents have to be changed manually when we want to change our letterhead or footer

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about the total number of Google Document files you want to use. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Thank you. I want to use 1 template document that has a header and a footer. (SOURCE DOCUMENT) Like this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hYlaz7AO3SnyLd07JAiFsUv4levSXudbl2zSlynogyM/edit

... Then, I want to REPLACE the header and footer in hundreds of documents which are in the same folder.  (replace all headers and footers with the header and footer from the SOURCE DOCUMENT).  Does that clarify?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I want to REPLACE the header and footer in hundreds of documents which are in the same folder.`, I'm worry whether the script can process such a lot of Document files in the execution time of 6 minutes. So, for example, how about separating your question? For example, 1. Copy header and footer for Google Document. 2. Process a lot of Google Document files. But I'm not sure whether this is the same direction you expect. If you want to resolve your question including both process as one question, please tell me.

Comment: Is there a 6 minute time limit?  If I can just figure out to replace the header and footer in ALL documents in a single folder with the TEMPLATE header and footer... I will separate the documents into other folders and run the script multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `Is there a 6 minute time limit?`, I couldn't understand about the answer you expect.

Comment: You mentioned execution time of 6 minutes.  I am OK with it taking all day, or as long as it takes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you will run the script for every several Documents, I think that the issue of the maximum execution time can be ignored.

Comment: Thank you.  I added a diagram here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hYlaz7AO3SnyLd07JAiFsUv4levSXudbl2zSlynogyM/edit.  I want to copy the TEMPLATE header and footer to REPLACE the header and footer in all documents in a folder .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225754/discussion-between-b-d-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the discussions, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- In your situation, the destination Documents have multiple pages and the texts have already been set, and you want to copy the header and footer of the template document to all pages of each destination document as the overwrite.
- From your shared Document,

  - I confirmed that in the header of the template document, the image is put in a table cell as a inline image.
  - I confirmed that in the footer of the template document, the image is used.
- When the image is used in a table, even when the table is copied, it seems that the image is not copied.

  - I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- From your replying comments, I could confirm as follows.

  - There are hundreds number of Google Document files you want to use.
  - But you will run the script for every several Documents.

In order to achieve your goal, in this sample script, I would like to propose the following flow.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve Google Document files from the specific folder.

   - In this case, the Document files are retrieved from just under the specific folder without checking the subfolders.
   - Because from your replying comments, although there are hundreds number of Google Document files you want to use, you will run the script for every several Documents.
2. Copy the header from the template Document to the destination Document.
3. Copy the footer from the template Document to the destination Document.

#### IMPORTANT:

As an important point, in the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that when the header and footer retrieved by `getHeader()` and `getFooter()` of Google Document service cannot identify whether the check of 1st page header is enabled and disabled. So in this sample script, the headers and footers both with and without the check of the 1st page header are overwritten.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor, and set the values of `templateDocumentId` and `folderId`, and then, run `main()`.

```
function getObjs(dstDoc, key) {
  if (!dstDoc.getHeader()) dstDoc.addHeader();  // Added
  if (!dstDoc.getFooter()) dstDoc.addFooter();  // Added

  var dd = dstDoc.getHeader().getParent();
  var cc = dd.getNumChildren();
  const objs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cc; i++) {
    if (dd.getChild(i).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType[key == "header" ? "HEADER_SECTION" : "FOOTER_SECTION"]) {
      objs.push(dd.getChild(i)[key == "header" ? "asHeaderSection" : "asFooterSection"]());
    }
  }
  return objs;
}

function copyFooter(tempDoc, dstDoc) {
  getObjs(dstDoc, "footer").forEach(dstFooter => {
    dstFooter.clear();
    const d = tempDoc.getFooter();
    const c = d.getNumChildren();
    for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      const child = d.getChild(i);
      const type = child.getType();
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        dstFooter.insertParagraph(i, child.copy().asParagraph());
      } if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
        dstFooter.insertTable(i, child.copy().asTable());
      }
    }
  });
}

function copyHeader(tempDoc, dstDoc) {
  getObjs(dstDoc, "header").forEach(dstHeader => {
    dstHeader.clear();
    const d = tempDoc.getHeader();
    const c = d.getNumChildren();
    for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
      const child = d.getChild(i);
      const type = child.getType();
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        dstHeader.insertParagraph(i, child.copy().asParagraph());
      } if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
        const table = child.copy().asTable();
        let imgObj = [];
        for (let r = 0, rows = table.getNumRows(); r < rows; r++) {
          const row = table.getRow(r);
          for (let c = 0, cols = row.getNumCells(); c < cols; c++) {
            const cell = row.getCell(c);
            for (let ce = 0, cc = cell.getNumChildren(); ce < cc; ce++) {
              if (cell.getChild(ce).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
                const cp = cell.getChild(ce).asParagraph();
                for (let cee = 0, cpn = cp.getNumChildren(); cee < cpn; cee++) {
                  const ceec = cp.getChild(cee);
                  if (ceec.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
                    const img = ceec.asInlineImage();
                    imgObj.push({child: cee, img: img, row: r, col: c, blob: img.getBlob(), width: img.getWidth(), height: img.getHeight()});
                    ceec.removeFromParent();
                  }
                }
              }
            }

          }
        }
        const dstTable = dstHeader.insertTable(i, table);
        if (imgObj.length > 0) {
          imgObj.forEach(({row, col, child, blob, width, height}) => dstTable.getCell(row, col).insertImage(child, blob).setWidth(width).setHeight(height));
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const templateDocumentId = "###";  // Please set the template Document ID.
  const folderId = "###";  // Please set the folder ID.

  const tempDoc = DocumentApp.openById(templateDocumentId);
  const docs = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  while (docs.hasNext()) {
    const docId = docs.next().getId();
    const dstDoc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    copyHeader(tempDoc, dstDoc);
    copyFooter(tempDoc, dstDoc);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script supposes that from your replying comments, although there are hundreds number of Google Document files you want to use, you will run the script for every several Documents. Please be careful this.
- This sample script is used for your sample template Document. Because I have only the information from your sample template Document. When you change the structure of the template Document, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document)
- [getHeader()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getheader)
- [getFooter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getfooter)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the reply.  I appreciate this.  This is much more complicated than I thought it would be.  Is there a way that I can make this more simple and applicable? e.g. make sure everything in the TEMPLATE header and footer is contained within a table?  I'm also a bit confused why this wouldn't work on hundreds of documents?  Is it an execution time issue?  The folder I am trying to do it on is G Suite and execution time limit is 1 hour I believe.    I'm willing to make changes to the template now to make updates simpler next time!

Comment: When I tried this code on examples -- I got Exception: Service unavailable: Documents (line 39, file "Code").     Line 39 is this:  dstHeader.insertParagraph(i, child.copy().asParagraph());      Is that a formatting issue within the header?

Comment: @B D Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about many questions in your 1st replying. About 2nd replying, as I said in my answer, this script is for your shared Document. Because I have only the information from your sample template Document. I apologize for this situation. So when the structure is different, that cannot be used. When you test this script, please your shared Document.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your script within the example document.  I get this error. Cannot read property 'getParent' of null (line 2, file "Code")

Does the script have to be OUTSIDE of the actual template document? 
I have the document ID as the template document, and the Folder ID replaced too

Comment: Is there a way to copy everything but the image? (the table and all formatting) and then insert the image after inserting the table and all formatting?  Is there an easier way to accomplish this (replace all headers and footers in a folder from a template doc) that you would suggest?  I can reformat the template header in a way to do this (e.g. put EVERYTHING in a single table) if that would simplify the process going forward.

Comment: @B D Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested your shared Document, no error occurs. The header and footer can be copied to other Document. So I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. But I would like to resolve your issue. So can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to replicate and confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: Hello, I opened the template document, added your script in the script editor, replaced the Template ID with the template document's ID, and folder ID with the folder containing the test documents that need header and footer replaced.  I tried to run the function main.  That is when I got the error: Cannot read property 'getParent' of null (line 2, file "Code")

Comment: @B D Thank you for replying. From your replying, I updated the script. I modified the function of `getObjs()`. Could you please confirm it? But I cannot still replicate your situation. So when this was not the solution of your current issue, I apologize.